# Disable the Elementor (template library or new features) popup when creating new items

Tags: elementor

Does anyone know a way to disable the Elementor (template library or new features) popup when creating new items?

This is an example when adding new popups https://capture.dropbox.com/D4MCKkvvwXeHmTFl